# NodeJS decodeURIComponent not working properly

Tags: node.js, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1, decodeuricomponent

When I tryed to decode the string below in nodeJS using decodeURLCompnent:

```
var decoded = decodeURI('Ulysses%20Guimar%C3%A3es%20-%20lado%20par');
console.log(decoded);
```

I got

```
Ulysses GuimarÃ£es - lado par
```

Instead of

```
Avenida Ulysses Guimarães - lado par
```

But when I use the same code on the client side (browser) I can get the right char 'ã'.

Is there a way to convert from **Ã£** to  **ã** in a Node script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot reproduce it in 0.10 or 0.11 versions of node.

You can convert first to second using `new Buffer('Ulysses GuimarÃ£es - lado par', 'binary').toString('utf8')`, but it's a workaround, not a solution.

Are you sure you're calling decodeURI, not unescape?

Answer (score 4):

Use `var querystring = require("querystring");`

The querystring.unescape() method performs decoding of URL percent-encoded characters on the given str.

and then `querystring.unescape(str)` as per docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_unescape_str

Answer (score 1):

I'm just leaving this here, because I had the same problem. I was using the `encodeURIcomponent(str)` function in the client and in Nodejs when I did `decodeURI(str)` had the same problem. I solved it by using `encodeURI(str)` at the client.

Comment: If you are using encodeURIcomponent you shold use "decodeURIComponent" and not "decodeURI".